# Flagging large dataset when unique IDs stop showing up in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

This is a pretty specific question but I have a large data set well over 1GB. The format of this data looks like:

```
Name         ID      OP Date      OP Hour        Gen         Heat
Jann         1       2001-01-01   1              10          0
Jann         1       2001-01-01   2              3           1
.
.
Jann         1       2001-01-01   24             13          3
Jann         2       2001-01-01   1              30          10
Jann         2       2001-01-01   3              32          11
.
.
Kay          1A      2002-01-01   1              0           12
Kay          1A      2002-01-01   2              2           22
.
.
.
.
.
Jann         1       2018-01-01   1              26          8
Jann         1       2018-01-01   2              32          21
```

Sometimes a `Name` will appear at some time not at the beginning of the data set (2001-01-01) and/or sometimes a `Name` will stop appearing in the data set all together at a certain `OP Date`.

Also, sometimes a `Name` will appear but only a certain `ID` from that `Name` will disappear.

I want to be able to know when a certain `Name` and `ID` **begin** and **end** in this data set.

For example `Jann ID 1` and `Jann ID 2` both start at `OP Date 2001-01-01` but `Jann ID 2` does not show up in `OP Date 2018-01-01`. Also, `Kay ID 1A` starts in `2002-01-01` but stops showing up somewhere before `2018-01-01`.

My desired output would be something like a dataframe:

```
Name         ID      OP Start Date     OP EndDate
Jann         1       2001-01-01        2018-01-01
Jann         2       2001-01-01        SOME OP DATE
Kay          1A      2002-01-01        SOME OP DATE
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a `groupby` and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) (or `aggregate`, it's the same function) to apply `first` and `last` on the `OP Date` for each Name / ID combo. This requires the df to be sorted by OP date (hence the use of `sort_values`)

```
# convert to datetime first if not done already
df['OP Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OP Date'])

df.sort_values('OP Date').groupby(['Name', 'ID'])['OP Date'].agg(['first', 'last'])


             first       last
Name ID                      
Jann 1  2001-01-01 2018-01-01
     2  2001-01-01 2001-01-01
Kay  1A 2002-01-01 2002-01-01
```